# Is it possible to set a mandatory requirement in DocuSign that requires the recipents to read the legal statement before they sign the contract?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

I have two agreements, one is the legal statement, the other one is the contract. I gonna put them into one envelope then sent it to recipients. I want the recipients to read the legal statement first before they signed the contract. I need to make sure they did read the statement then signed the contract. Is it possible to accomplish with DocuSign? For now,I'm sending contracts out by DocuSign.

It would be truely appeciated that someone can help me with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make sure someone reads something. I'm not aware of such technology. It requires to connect the person to electrodes and scan the position of their eyes to know if the brain did the reading.

What you can do is ensure that they clicked a link that opens the document and that they scrolled down to the end of the document. That doesn't mean they read it, believe me, I did this many times, didn't read a word, but clicked here and there and finished the process.

If that works for you - then all you have to do is use DocuSign regularly and put a signature at the end, the system will require the user to scroll to the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you mean I can put a signature in the end of the legal statement then the recipients have to scoll to the end. I think it's a way to confirm the legal statement known by the recipients.(that's what I want)
But how to let the contract show after the recipients signed the legal statement? The contract must come after the legal statement. There are two separate documents while they cannot put in one template. The legal statement comes first, then the recipients will read about it. They can only sign the contract after signed the legal statement.

Comment: correct, try it and see

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign doesn't directly support this on the key eSignature platform. However, we do have a few systems that might help.

We do have an agreement system created for Click agreements called Elastic Templates. Elastic Templates exist as part of a mostly separate system that's meant for click to agree actions for things like User disclosures.

In your case, this would have you add a javascript snip that would load the agreement. More relevant to your issue one of the loading parameters you can set is onagreed(){} where you could initiate a createEnvelope action only after DocuSign returns that the user has already agreed to the initial Elastic Template.

Think of it as going to a website, clicking the "I agree to T&C", then agreeing . Once you've agreed to the terms it should move past the initial step.

Within the eSign system, we have Supplemental Documents that are required to view, but you have far less control over what order the customer sees.

Feel free to open a Support case and either myself or someone on my team can help look into options for you.

Regards - Matt King | Sr. Developer Advisory Engineer | DocuSign

Comment: See the view_accept option and requiredRead attributes.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does support this type of "scroll all the way to the end" behavior for documents. See the `view_accept` option of the `signerMustAcknowledge` attribute. [Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_documents_signermustacknowledge)

Also see the `viewTab` and its `requiredRead` attribute. [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_recipients_signers_tabs_viewtabs_requiredread)

Here's a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Supplemental%20documents%20in%20four%20styles) you can try.